# Using -d with 2 versions of the same domain in Certbot

Tags: certbot

For Using -d with 2 versions of the same domain in Certbot I tried the following.

Instead doning:

`certbot --nginx` and then chosing 1+2 (for domain.tld + www.domain.tld), I did:

certbot --nginx -d contfix.co.il, -d www.contfix.co.il

But I got:

```
Requested domain is not a FQDN because it contains an empty label.
```

Why Certbot won't accept the collection?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason is that I used a comma. The comma is redundant.

This worked:

```
certbot --nginx -d contfix.co.il -d www.contfix.co.il
```